# React inline css placing brackets directly in html output

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm attempting to use an inline style in react, which I created with create-react app.

From what I've seen, the following should work properly:

```html
<div id="root" style={{ height: 'auto' }}></div>
```

However, the following is output in the HTML when I run `yarn start`:

[image]

When I choose "edit html" in chrome, it looks like this:

```html
<div id="root" style="{{" height:="" 'auto'="" }}="">
```

Why is my `{{ }}` not working? Have I missed something? Or does create-react-app need something extra configured in webpack or babel?

Perhaps relevant, I have run [`eject`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts/#npm-run-eject) but haven't changed any of the default settings that could affect this as far as I know.

Comment: The react syntax is not something a web browser can parse.

Comment: Back to the basics!  Thanks for responding @dehart. What do I need to do then?

Comment: If you do the same exact thing on a fresh `create-react-app` project, do you get the same result? You said you ejected it, but are you sure you didn't change anything?

Comment: Thanks all, if you look at the answer provided - it was a basic confusion between just plain HTML and react HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing between [style attribute](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style) in [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) and [style attribute in HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/style).

```
// HTML @ index.html
<div style="background: blue; height: 50px; width: 50px;"/>

// JSX @ Component.js
<div style={{ background: 'blue', height: 50, width: 50 }} />

// Transpiled to
React.createElement("div", {
  style: {
    background: 'blue',
    height: 50,
    width: 50
  }
});
```

Comment: Ah of course, I can't just put this in the plain index.html!! Many thanks.